# Django does not see a change in the primary key data type

Tags: python, django

In the data model, I changed the data type from INT to VarChar for the ID field. Unfortunately, this change was not noticed by macemigrations and I was forced to do a migrate zero and generate the migration file from scratch. Unfortunately, this didn't help either, as the ID field was still of type INT. Therefore, I modified the file and did the migrations. A table as I expected was created in the database. I even did a manual INSERT into the database which ended up being a succes. Unfortunately, Django has a problem with the insert and throws an error :

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got '230301-001'.

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.1.249:8080/maintenance/new
Django Version:     4.1.3
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

Field 'id' expected a number but got '230301-001'.
```

I also paste the stack:

```
/home/gaza/projects/django/maintenance/models.py, line 60, in save

            super(Report, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

     …

Local vars
Variable    Value
__class__   <class 'maintenance.models.Report'>
args        ()
id_date     '230301'
kwargs      {}
new_id      '230301-001'
qs          <QuerySet []>
self        <Report: 230301--001>
today       datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1, 14, 19, 41, 369941)
user        <SimpleLazyObject: <User: superadmin>>
```

Below is my model definition and the SQL itself from the database that created the tables.

```
class Report(ModelBaseClass):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, verbose_name='custom ID'),
    created_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False, verbose_name='Przyjmując')
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Klient')
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='E-mail')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Telefon')
    phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='custom ID')
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, verbose_name='Uwagi do zgłoszenia')
    registration_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Data przyjęcia')
    ending_date = models.DateTimeField('Data zakończenia', null=True, blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = get_current_user()
        if user and not user.pk:
            user = None
        if not self.pk:
            self.created_user = user
     # Generowanie ID
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        id_date = today.strftime('%y%m%d')
        qs = Report.objects.filter(id__startswith=id_date).order_by('-id')
        if qs.exists():
            last_id = qs.first().id
            last_num = int(last_id[-3:])
            new_num = last_num + 1
            new_id = '{0}-{1:03d}'.format(id_date, new_num)
        else:
            new_id = '{0}-001'.format(id_date)

        self.id = new_id
        self.modified_by = user
        super(Report, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Naprawa'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Naprawy'
        ordering = ['registration_date']
```

And SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.maintenance_report
(
    id character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    created_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    modified_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    email character varying(254) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    phone character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    phone1 character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    comment text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    registration_date date NOT NULL,
    ending_date timestamp with time zone,
    client_id integer NOT NULL,
    created_user_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT maintenance_report_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT maintenance_report_client_id_314fc97c_fk_organize_client_id FOREIGN KEY (client_id)
        REFERENCES public.organize_client (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT maintenance_report_created_user_id_8c533531_fk_auth_user_id FOREIGN KEY (created_user_id)
        REFERENCES public.auth_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
```

I paste a screenshot of a direct attempt to create an object from a shell:

```
In [16]: new_id
Out[16]: '230301-001'

In [17]: report = Report(id=new_id,created_user=user,client=client)

In [18]: report.save()
<class 'str'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value(self, value)
   2017         try:
-> 2018             return int(value)
   2019         except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '230301-001'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-27511b8eb600> in <module>
----> 1 report.save()

~/projects/django/maintenance/models.py in save(self, *args, **kwargs)
     58         self.id = new_id
     59         self.modified_by = user
---> 60         super(Report, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
     61
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this error ?

Comment: I think the problem is in your view, maybe the validation is still asking for an integer instead of a string, maybe you need to check that first.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. As is usually the case in such cases, I made the problem myself. In the model file in the first line, where it defines the mid field, there is a comma "," at the end, which is why django did not want to do the migration and therefore did not see the changes between the table definition in the database , and the model file.

Two days lost.

Greetings

Gaza