# Primary Key varchar - no detection of model changes

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

PostgreSql database, Django 4.

I have a problem with detecting data model changes to a migration file. I am trying to add my primary key of type varchar which has format dddddd-ddd in the model. The field definition itself looks like this :
`mid = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, verbose_name='custom ID'),`
Unfortunately, after creating the migration file, you can't see the **mid** field, but there is an **id**.
To test the correctness of the makemigrations itself, I added the phone1 field, which is already detected and has coverage in the migration.

Here is my model

```
class Report(ModelBaseClass):
    mid = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, verbose_name='custom ID'),
    created_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False, verbose_name='Przyjmując')
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Klient')
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='E-mail')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Telefon')
    phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Telefon')
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, verbose_name='Uwagi do zgłoszenia')
    registration_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Data przyjęcia')
    ending_date = models.DateTimeField('Data zakończenia', null=True, blank=True)
```

And an excerpt from the migration file.

```
  migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Report',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('modified_date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, null=True, verbose_name='E-mail')),
                ('phone', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, null=True, verbose_name='Telefon')),
                ('phone1', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, null=True, verbose_name='Telefon')),
                ('comment', models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=1000, verbose_name='Uwagi do zgłoszenia')),
                ('registration_date', models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Data przyjęcia')),
                ('ending_date', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data zakończenia')),
                ('client', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='organize.client', verbose_
                ('created_user', models.ForeignKey(editable=False, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to=setti
            ],
```

How to fix it

PS. started a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75604972/django-does-not-see-a-change-in-the-primary-key-data-type) about the same issue but already a step forward. However, I think the root cause is the migration itself and that's where I need to start.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. As is usually the case in such cases, I made the problem myself. In the model file in the first line, where it defines the mid field, there is a comma "," at the end, which is why django did not want to do the migration and therefore did not see the changes between the table definition in the database , and the model file.

Greetings
Gaza